# Can't update SQL Server 2008 to SP3, it only offers the option to create a new instance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, troubleshooting

A colleague is attempting to update our server's SQL Server 2008 version 10.0.1600.22 (not R2) install up to SP3.  Unfortunately, we can't work out where the "Update" button is; the installer seems to be set on creating a new instance, which isn't what we're after.

Windows Update doesn't seem to be finding the update either, so we can't do it that way.

What are we missing, here?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are using install media not a service pack installer.  [Download the service pack executable](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=27594) and try again.  Windows update will only show it if the "get updates for other Microsoft products" option was chosen.